# Force canvas element in html to take up the entire window?

Tags: html, canvas

Instead of

```
<pre>
    <canvas id="theCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</pre>
```

where I specify the size of the canvas is there a way to make the canvas take up the entire browser window?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize HTML5 canvas to fit window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664785/resize-html5-canvas-to-fit-window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html>
  <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0;">
    <canvas style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is inappropriate, as the width and height attributes of the canvas element are needed for correct scaling. The right solution is to detect the width and height of the window and adjust accordingly to avoid aliasing effects.

Answer (score 4):

When you are creating a canvas element that spans the entire screen, you are probably going to want to monitor for window resizing events. You can go ahead and use a percentage based style, but you will have to remember to repaint your canvas whenever the window is resized; when a canvas element's dimensions are altered (width or height) the canvas itself is cleared and effectively reset (origin policies are an exception).

I suggest you use something like this:

```
window.addEventListener(
  'resize', 
  function() { 
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth; 
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight; 
    MyRepaintCallback(); 
  }, 
  false);
```

There are several considerations for your repaint function beyond the scope of this question. At least, rest assured, knowing that double buffering will likely keep your canvas from flickering between repainting calls.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, set width and height to 100% for html, body (and form if asp.net) tags.

Does not work in older IEs, though.