# Make canvas fill the whole page

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How can I make canvas be 100% in width and height of the page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize HTML5 canvas to fit window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664785/resize-html5-canvas-to-fit-window)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Well I have it working here: [Are Google's Bouncing Balls HTML5?](http://www.aregooglesbouncingballshtml5.com/) by using the following CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body, html { height:100%; }

#c {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Where #c is the id of the canvas element.

Comment: No, this doesn't work. It just stretches the image to fill the page, but it doesn't change the internal width and height of the canvas. The result is just a blurry mess.

Comment: To remove scrollbars, use `canvas { display: block; }` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31204041/5231110).

Comment: @zett42 Are you getting different results from setting `width` to `100%` vs. something like `window.innerWidth` as per other answers, even though those two "values" have the same meaning? How is that possible?  Maybe all answers here require redrawing the canvas image, not only this answer?

Answer (score 17):

you can use these codes without jquery

```
var dimension = [document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientHeight];
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
c.width = dimension[0];
c.height = dimension[1];
```

Answer (score 13):

```
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

maybe that easy?

Answer (score 10):

This has something to do with `<canvas>` tag.

when create fullscreen canvas, `<canvas>` will cause scrollbar if not set to display:block.

detail: http://browser.colla.me/show/canvas_cannot_have_exact_size_to_fullscreen

Comment: Best answer!
The only thing that worked for me.
I only had to add this one rule.

Comment: `canvas { display: block; }` seems to work nicely in combination with [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3707579/5231110).

Answer (score 1):

You can programatically set the canvas width + height:

```
// Using jQuery to get window width + height.
canvasObject.width = $(window).width();
canvasObject.height = $(window).height();
```

I've tested this and it as long as you redraw what's on the canvas after you've resized it won't change the scaling.

Answer (score 1):

on my observations this runs effectively, and gives a blue shade

---

```
var c = document.getElementById('can');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // add linear gradient
  var g = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  // light blue color
  g.addColorStop(0, '#8ED6FF');   
  // dark blue color
  g.addColorStop(1, '#004CB3');
  context.fillStyle = g;
  context.fill();
```

```js
<script>
var c = document.getElementById('can');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      // add linear gradient
      var g = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
      // light blue color
      g.addColorStop(0, '#8ED6FF');   
      // dark blue color
      g.addColorStop(1, '#004CB3');
      context.fillStyle = g;
      context.fill();
</scrip
```

```css
html,body
{
 height:98.0%;
 width:99.5%;
}
canvas
{
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="can"></canvas>
</body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
<html>
  <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0;">
    <canvas style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

from [Force canvas element in html to take up the entire window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517951/force-canvas-element-in-html-to-take-up-the-entire-window)

Comment: It sets width to 100%, but doesn't make it in height 100%. More than that, the objects is scaled too and looks like a small raster image had been enlarged so it looks weird. What can I do about this?